# Microsoft Dynamics CRM on-premises Migration to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to migrate Microsoft Dynamics CRM on-premises 2015 to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016 without use service Scribe or another service.

the steps I want to use is:

1 : export a special solution called the Default Solution. The Default Solution contains all the components in CRM and import in CRM Online.

2 : Export Data to Excel for all entities in CRM on-premises and import in CRM Online.

3 : map users CRM with AD Office 365.

Is this correct steps?
Any another way to migrate or ideas ?

Comment: If your Online org is hosted in the North America region, you could use the new [Data Loader service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2015/10/08/preview-feature-data-loader-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-online.aspx). Also be aware that you will not be able to migrate Attachments using Excel export/import. From my experience, you'll soon come to the point where you'll some sort of tool to migrate your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your steps are just right.
Just be advised, CRM Online has new functionality not included in CRM 2015 on-premise, you do need to check that features.

For two reasons:

- Something might stop working
- Something might continue working but there's a new functionality in CRM Online that already does it without coding.

And I would add another step, check that all of the workflows are Active, after adding the users .

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to migrate a small amount of data, you can use the Data Migration tool in the SDK.  It's better than the Excel imports.

Comment: thank you Darly,now I m used  Data Migration tool in the SDK

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same task to migrate crm on premise organization to crm online organization. I also follow the same steps. Here are some of the things I have learned so far,

- Plugins implemented in full trust mode did not worked in online
  environment because it only supports the sandbox mode for plugings.
- It's better to use data migration tool such as MSCRM Toolkit. But
  unable to maintain to ownership of the record.